# FluentNHibernate.Mapping.Builders namespace

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I want to try a class from the FluentNHibernate.Mapping.Builders namespace called CompositeElementBuilder but after setting a reference to the FluentNHibernate assembly I can can't get this namespace. Is there a separate assembly that contains the FluentNHibernate.Mapping.Builders namespace?

Thanks,

Matthew

Answer (score 1):

No it should be in that assembly.  I just looked through the object browser and I saw it.
Did you remember your: using FluentNHibernate.Mapping.Builders;

**Edit:**

I am using version 1.1.0.0.
This does not appear to be in version 1.1.0.685 (Current on website).

Comment: Yes. I put the using statement but Builders does not show in the Intellisense and it won't build with the using statement. I really don't get it. Makes no sense. I am missing something simple I'm sure but I just cant' put my finger on it. I can't see the Builders namespace in Object browser either. I just got the main download link at fluentnhibernate.org.

Comment: I downloaded Fluent again and reset the reference to FluentNHibernate.dll but that did not help.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 32 bit and Visual Studio 2010 and building to .Net 4. I hope those are all valid options.

Comment: OK. That explains it. I'll checkthe github and see if there are any release notes about that change. Thanks.